# gccgo-cross-compile can't compile cgo

Tags: go, gcc, cross-compiling, cgo, gccgo

I am trying to compile a simple go program using gccgo. My code uses cgo thou, gccgo couldn't compile it. This is my code (which compiles using go compiler):

```
package main

// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
//
// static void myprint(char* s) {
//   printf("%s\n", s);
// }
import "C"
import "fmt"
func main(){
    fmt.Println("Start")
    cs := C.CString("Print from C")
    C.myprint(cs)
    fmt.Println("End")
}
```

when I compile the code using `gccgo main.go -o gccoutput` I get:

```
main.go:9:9: error: import file ‘C’ not found
 import "C"
         ^
main.go:13:8: error: reference to undefined name ‘C’
  cs := C.CString("Print from C")
        ^
main.go:14:2: error: reference to undefined name ‘C’
  C.myprint(cs)
  ^
```

any ideas how to solve this?

**EDIT:**
I am trying to compile to ppc using the gccgo, and I don't want to use cross-compilation process of go compiler. I have tried to do (as suggested in the comments):

```
go build -compiler=gccgo
```

and it worked. Thou, when I do:

```
go build -comiler=powerpc-linux-gnu-gccgo main.go
```

I get:

```
invalid value "powerpc-linux-gnu-gccgo" for flag -compiler: unknown compiler "powerpc-linux-gnu-gccgo"
usage: go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help build' for details.
```

Comment: [This](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/go-import-work-with-cgo-not-with-gccgo/5176)? I mean, does it work if you use `go build -compiler=gccgo`?

Comment: Do you know the explain what does it do? what is the difference between that and calling directly to gccgo?

Comment: `cgo` is a `go` tool, so you need to use `go` to generate the `C` package.

Comment: thank you, that helped. I have edit the question since it is more complex then I thought at the beginning

Comment: What @JimB, said, yes: interfacing Go with C is a complex task which is carried out by the dedicated subsystem called [`cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/).

Comment: The edit to your original question had actually made it another question completely ;-) The thing is, the `-compiler` option to `go` is not the name of the compiler binary but rather the name of a supported "suite", of which there are two: `gc` (the built-in, stock one) and `gccgo`. What you probably need is to use appropriate environment variables to tell `gcc` which cross-compiler to use. Please read carefully [this document](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/).

Comment: Regarding the `-compile` option, it is documented [here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies).